# Syntax error when POST data with JQuery to coldfusion function

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a cfm page with multiple dropdowns (some are cfselect) and dynamically generated lists of checkboxes interdependent on each other. I am using JQuery to submit data to cfc functions and to display data.

I am getting error "The PLANENROLLDATE_ID parameter to the GetBillsArr function is required but was not passed in. 
The error occurred on line -1. "

In the console planenrolldate_id looks like array.
From console:

```
fM  9
fY  2014
method  GetBillsArr
planenrolldate_id[] 564
planenrolldate_id[] 561
sponsor_id  59
tM  9
tY  2014
```

This is how multiple checked planenrolldate_id looks in console

```
["564", "559", "524", "517", "459", "438", "402", "390"]
```

Below is jquery function:

```
 function populateBills(){
   var plID = $('#planenrolldate_id').val();
   var sID = $('#sponsor_id').val(); 
   var pID = $('#plan_id').val();
   var fromMonth = $('#from_month').val();
   var fromYear = $('#from_year').val();
   var toMonth = $('#to_month').val();
   var toYear = $('#to_year').val();

   $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url:"../components/billing/custompremstat.cfc?method=GetBillsArr",
     data: {
        sponsor_id: sID,
        planenrolldate_id: plID,
        fM: fromMonth, 
        fY: fromYear, 
        tM: toMonth, 
        tY: toYear
      },
      success: 
        function(data){                  
          $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            addBillsCheckboxes(item.bill_id,item.bill_period);
         });
       },
       error: 
         function(){
            alert("An error has occurred while fetching bills");
          }
        });
      }
```

This it coldfuion function cfc part:

```
<cffunction name="GetBillsArr" access="remote" returnFormat="json" returnType="array">
  <cfargument name="sponsor_id" type="any" required="true">
  <cfargument name="planenrolldate_id" type="any" required="true">
  <cfargument name="fM" type="numeric" required="true">
  <cfargument name="fY" type="numeric" required="true">
  <cfargument name="tM" type="numeric" required="true">
  <cfargument name="tY" type="numeric" required="true">

  <cfset var result=ArrayNew(1)>

  <cfif ARGUMENTS.planenrolldate_id EQ "" OR ARGUMENTS.sponsor_id EQ "">
    <cfset LstBills = QueryNew("bill_id, bill_period", "Integer, Varchar")>
  <cfelse>
    <cfquery name="LstBills" ...>
       SELECT bill_id,
         (Convert(varchar(10),billing_start_date,103) + ' - ' + Convert(varchar(10),billing_end_date,103)) + ' [' + Convert(varchar(6),plan_id) + ']' AS bill_period
         FROM ...
    </cfquery>            
   </cfif>

   <cfloop query="LstBills">
       <cfset returnStruct = StructNew()>
       <cfset returnStruct["bill_id"]= bill_id>
       <cfset returnStruct["bill_period"] = bill_period>
       <cfset ArrayAppend(result,returnStruct) />
   </cfloop>

   <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

This is part of cfm file

```
<cfselect name="plan_id" bind="url:../components/billing/custompremstatus.cfc?method=GetPlans&langpref_id=#REQUEST.SESS.langpref_id#&sponsor_id={sponsor_id.value}&user_sup_list=0&returnFormat=json" display="name" value="plan_id" multiple="yes" bindonload="false" />

<cfselect name="planenrolldate_id" size="5" bind="url:../components/billing/custompremstatus.cfc?method=GetPlanEnrollments&sponsor_id={sponsor_id.value}&plan_id={plan_id.value}&returnFormat=json" display="enroll_period" value="planenrolldate_id" multiple="yes" bindonload="false" />

<em>FROM</em> 
                    <select name="from_month" id="from_month">
                        <option value="0">Select Month</option>
                        <cfloop from="1" to="12" index="i">
                            <option value="<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>" <cfif Month(Now()) Eq i>selected</cfif>><cfoutput>#MonthAsString(i)#</cfoutput></option>
                        </cfloop>
                    </select>
                    /
                    <select name="from_year" id="from_year">
                        <option value="0">Select Year</option>
                        <cfset VARIABLES.iYearFrom = Year(Now()) - 10>
                        <cfset VARIABLES.iYearTo = Year(Now()) + 10>
                        <cfloop from="#VARIABLES.iYearFrom#" to="#VARIABLES.iYearTo#" index="i">
                            <option value="<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>" <cfif Year(Now()) Eq i>selected</cfif>><cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput></option>
                        </cfloop>
                    </select>

     <div id="billid"></div>
```

==================UPDATE====================================

This is html generated by cfselect

```
<tr>
 <td width="100">Plans:</td>
  <td width="400">
    <select name="plan_id" id="plan_id" multiple="multiple" size="5" >
  </select> 
 </tr>

<tr>
 <td width="100">Enrollment Periods:</td>
  <td width="400">
    <select name="planenrolldate_id" id="planenrolldate_id" multiple="multiple" size="5" >
  </select> 
 </tr>
```

Comment: What does the `data` look like if you output it to the console in the error handler?

Comment: This is from console Response tab: "The PLANENROLLDATE_ID parameter to the GetBillsArr function is required but was not passed in. The error occurred on line -1. ".

Comment: ... and what does the data you're passing to that function look like?

Comment: and this from previous drop down, the one that preceding drop down with error: {"COLUMNS":["PLANENROLLDATE_ID","ENROLL_PERIOD"],"DATA":[[1115,"01\/01\/2014 - 31\/12\/2014 [342]"]]}

Comment: What does the HTML generated by your two `cfselect` tags look like?

Comment: I added HTML to the UPDATE of my original post